# Why QML is too slow and can't draw a scene with ~4000 simple elements?

Tags: qt, qml

I am trying to use QT's QML to render a scene which is a 32x32 grid of elements each containing one rectangle and 12 circles. There is a .qml file for a tile, and another, blank .qml file for an empty space between tiles. So the QML Grid has ~4000 tiles: ~1000 with a square and 12 circles, and ~3000 with just a colored square.

Redrawing of such scene takes >0.5 sec or more, which is very slow. OpenGL is used for rendering. I think the core of the problem is that it has to call JavaScript functions thousands of times.

Is QML a wrong technology for such work? From the QML description it seems like it is a modern toolkit and it should work well in game-like situations with a lot of dynamic objects.

If the screen is full of dynamic small objects it should be able to comfortably redraw a scene as long as objects are visible, like OpenGL does. Is QML fundamentally less capable than OpenGL?

For each of 32x32 tiles it calls drawCircle 12 times:

```
        var drawCircle = function(x,y, R) {
                context.beginPath();
                context.fillStyle = "yellow"
                context.strokeStyle = "darkgray"
                context.lineWidth = "2"
                context.moveTo(x+R, y);
                context.arc(x,y, R, 0, 2*Math.PI, true)
                context.fill();
                context.stroke();
        };
```

and it draws the rectangle once:

```
        context.beginPath();
        context.fillStyle = "lightgray"
        context.fillRect(width*marginLeft, height*marginTop, width - width*(marginLeft+marginRight), height - height*(marginTop+marginBottom));
        context.fill();
```

For empty space it calls the above rectangle drawing code ~3000 times.

Comment: Add code showing what kind of items are painted.

Comment: @FrankOsterfeld Added the code above.

Comment: For performance questions, try using the [qml profiler](https://doc.qt.io/qtcreator/creator-qml-performance-monitor.html). Are you able to use simple `Rectangle` objects instead of using a canvas drawing?

Comment: Rectangle objects wouldn't fit my needs because I will need generally more elaborate drawing than just rectangles.

Comment: As I know custom painting in QML can be implemented in 3 ways - `QQuickItem`, `QQuickPaintedItem` and `Canvas`. The first one in the fastest, the last one is the slowest. So if the performance is critical for you maybe you have to look at other options.

Comment: Context2D is a very inefficient way to paint many items, every items is painted individually using QPainter (using the CPU), and then transferred to the GPU. You probably need to find a way to utilize the GPU better, like using images or custom shaders, and if the items are uniform, avoid doing the same work for every single item separately.

Comment: I'd have a look at the QML profiler first though, it might also be that painting isn't your bottleneck alone, but e.g. binding evaluation is.

Comment: Please try looking into QtQuick OpenGL. Also, read this blog for further details on benchmarking 
https://www.vikingsoftware.com/qtquick-custom-item-performance/